# Learning SQL Server. Why cant i insert into a date column?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Why cant I insert this date in to this table that I have just created?

```
create table Car (  ID int NOT NULL constraint PKID Primary Key,
                    Manufacturer varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
                    Model varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
                    Colour varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
                    Mileage int, 
                    DateOfRegistration Date NOT NULL,
                    NumberPlate varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
                    [4x4] bit NOT NULL, 
                    PreviousOwners smallint,
                    MotExpiry date not null)

Insert into Car (ID, Manufacturer, Model, Colour, DateOfRegistration, NumberPlate, [4x4], MotExpiry) 
Values 
(1000001, 'Nissan', 'XTrail','Green', 2014, 'EK64 XEJ', 1, '2018-11-26')
```

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 15 Operand type clash: int is
>   incompatible with date

Answer (score 1):

2014 is a number, not a date. If DateOfRegistration is really just YearOfRegistration change its type to int.

Otherwise change 2014 to '2014-01-01' or some other string that SQL Server can parse as a date.

Answer (score 0):

`DateOfRegistration` is a `DATE` type and you are trying to insert `2014` which is an `INTEGER`. Either insert a `DATE`, or change the datatype to `INTEGER` if you are only going to insert the `YEAR`.

```
alter table Car 
alter column DateOfRegistration int
```

Or, insert the date of registration as a date...

```
Insert into Car (ID, Manufacturer, Model, Colour, DateOfRegistration,NumberPlate, [4x4], MotExpiry) 
Values 
(1000001, 'Nissan', 'XTrail','Green', getdate(), 'EK64 XEJ', 1, '2018-11-26')
```

Comment: No problem @graham and don't forget [to read this blog](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on answers :)